# Weird character when trying to output Double amount in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

Good day

When trying to show a double amount using Freemarker, this weird character is inserted in the amount: Â

```
Example of original amount: 1257.12
Freemarker output: 1Â 257,12
```

Why would this be the case?

EDIT:

Fixed this by setting the character set to UTF8 in the header portion of the ftlx file.

Comment: You might want to provide some more code, e.g. the template as well as how you feed the parameters to it. My guess would be that it's an encoding problem with the template trying to render the grouping separator.

Comment: maybe it is some currency symbol the font/encoding cannot display

Comment: I suspect it's a "thousands separator" in some culture, combined with an encoding mismatch. What's your system culture?

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, it is South Africa and it uses a space, for example: 1 234 567

Comment: Ah, that explains it. It's not a regular space, it's a non-breaking space. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is an encoding mismatch representation of [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), which is the South African number group separator - a non-breaking space.

The UTF-8 representation of U+00A0 is two bytes: 0xC2 0xA0. When those bytes are decoded as if they're ISO-8859-1, you end up with U+00C2 U+00A0 - which is "Â" followed by the non-breaking space.

So basically, if you can convince everything involved to use the same encoding - ideally UTF-8 - you should be fine.

Comment: Also, it often happens that the default number format of Java for a certain locale is not what users want as the default. (Not to mention, that in theory that can change for new Java versions.) In that case, a `java.text.spi.NumberFormatProvider` can be used to override that. Or, if the default number format is only a problem in templates, the `number_format` configuration setting of FreeMarker can be used.

Comment: Thanks @ddekany looking into using your suggestion to set this globally for the project.